# VBA Named Range that contains offsets is fixed in chart

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dynamic table with values in column Y:

I create `series1` in name manager with the formula
`=OFFSET('Sheet1'!$Y$16,0,0,COUNTA('Sheet1'!$Y$16:$Y$5012),1)`

I want to plot this via a chart in VBA, so I do

`cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:="=series1"`

but what I get in my graph is `"='Sheet1'!$Y$16:$Y$43"` because data stops in line 43

instead of

`='static bbg data'!series1`

So later if I add lines to my table in column Y, these won't be updated on the graph vs is I were to create my chart and add `='static bbg data'!series1` manually.

Could you help me to solve this?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Add an update procedure

Place an update procedure into a module

```
Sub UpdateChartSourceData()
    With Worksheets("SheetWithChart")
        cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range("series1")
    End With
End Sub
```

And put this in your sheet with the chart data

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("series1")) Is Nothing Then
        cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Me.Range("series1")
    End If
End Sub
```

to update the chart everytime the data changes.

You might need to define/adjust `cht` in the code above.

---

#### Or use formatted tables

An easier way would be to use a formatted table for source data. And make the chart using that complete table as source. This way the chart automatically updates if the table gets added rows or columns.

Comment: The formatted table is a good choice. An alternative that you did not mention is to add a line "inside" the "old" range to extend it and then move the values around.